# Can a thread be moved into another thread?

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
fn main() {
    let queue = Arc::new(Mutex::new(VecDeque::new())); //because of the move keyword to move the thread t into the
    let q_clone = queue.clone();
    thread::scope(move |s| {
        //let q_cl = queue
        let t = s.spawn(move || loop {
            let item = queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front();
            if let Some(item) = item {
                dbg!(item);
            } else {
                thread::park();
            }
        });
        s.spawn(move || {
            for i in 1.. {
                q_clone.lock().unwrap().push_back(i);
                t.thread().unpark();
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here in the second thread spawn, there is the use of the `move` keyword
I have two questions:

1. What is happening with the `Arc` from what I understand, `Arc` provides a reference and cloning it will just increase the reference count, so according to me a reference just needs to be borrowed there is no need to take ownership, but on removing the move it gives an error.
2. In the second thread spawn, is the thread `t` moved into the other thread, if not how does this ensure that the lifetime of thread `t` is less than the lifetime of the second thread.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

Threads aren't values that you can move around, `spawn` only gives you a [`ScopedJoinHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.ScopedJoinHandle.html) through which you can interact with the thread.<sup>1</sup> There is no guarantee that either thread outlives the other.

The error is not related to `Arc` at all here, infact you don't need it. It's because the closure you pass to `thread::scope()` is run before your threads are, and thus `t` which is a local variable goes out of scope with it.

This code:

```rust
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
fn main() {
    let queue = &Mutex::new(VecDeque::new());
    thread::scope(|s| {
        let t = s.spawn(|| loop {
            let item = queue.lock().unwrap().pop_front();
            if let Some(item) = item {
                dbg!(item);
            } else {
                thread::park();
            }
        });
        s.spawn(move || {
            for i in 1.. {
                queue.lock().unwrap().push_back(i);
                t.thread().unpark();
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

does work as you expect it, the second closure needs `move` because else `t` is dropped before it's used.

---

<sup>1: No, [`Thread`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Thread.html) isn't an actual thread either, it's *"A handle to a thread."*</sup>

Comment: But in thread t there is a loop so it shouldn't terminate that easily, also don't both of the threads have the same scope

Comment: They are created in the same scope, but that doesn't mean anything for variables created in the closure passed to `thread::scope()`, nor does it mean anything for the scopes of each thread.